# How can I customize the size of the header of my theme?

Tags: functions, custom-header

I want to change the size of my header using the Sparkling theme. In functions.php, right below this:

```
/**
 * Implement the Custom Header feature.
 */
```

I added this:

```
add_theme_support( 'custom-header' );
```

Below that I pasted this from custom-header.php:

```
function sparkling_custom_header_setup() {  
    add_theme_support( 
        'custom-header', 
        apply_filters( 
            'sparkling_custom_header_args', 
            array(  
                'default-image'          => '',  
                'default-text-color'     => 'dadada',  
                'width'                  => 300,   
                'height'                 => 76,   
                'flex-height'            => true,  
                'flex-width'             => true,  
                'wp-head-callback'       => 'sparkling_header_style',  
                'admin-head-callback'    => 'sparkling_admin_header_style',  
                'admin-preview-callback' => 'sparkling_admin_header_image',  
            ) 
        ) 
    );
}
```

But customizing the width and height did nothing. I also tried setting up a "flexible header" and pasted a different array template into functions.php along with this in header.php:

```
<img src="<?php header_image(); ?>" height="<?php echo get_custom_header()->height; ?>" width="<?php echo get_custom_header()->width; ?>" alt="" />
```

The latter lines I tried in various locations/permutations, as a substitute for some very similar looking code already within header.php, and in addition to that code. Still nothing.

Comment: Please format your code to display properly.

Answer (score 0):

1) see the reference - http://codex.wordpress.org/Custom_Headers

or

2) You can insert like this in header.php :  `<img class="somethingg" style="width:400px;height:200px;"  ................  />`

Comment: Where do I put the <img class="somethingg" ....... /> ? In functions.php? Where within functions.php? After add_theme_support( 'custom-header' ); ? Are those periods meant to be literally periods or representing something else I'm supposed to fill in?